# Angular App not serving latest build files to end users

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an Angular Web App that has more frequent changes so when I build and publish to IIS, app is not serving latest build files to end users. It is required to press Ctrl + F5 to get new files from the server.

I use below CLI command to produce build files. I use Angular 8.

> ng build --aot --outputHashing=bundles --prod

Should I add any other parameter for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and discovered it comes from the web server (Apache in my case).

When you deploy the app on production, the root file (`index.html`) contains the following code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="/runtime.937c2b326bb921beac97.js" defer></script>
        <script src="/polyfills.a78c48dee545feb95e6a.js" defer></script>
        <script src="/scripts.14a9d42d0791cb2fa37d.js" defer></script>
        <script src="/main.57de7a395d76adaeeb43.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

By default, my Apache serveur cached the JS files and the `index.html`. So when I deployed a new version, the users still got the old `index.html` which references the old JS files.

To fix this, I forced the browser not to cache the `index.html`. It is fetched everytime the app load in the browser so the version is always the latest, and so the JS files.

Apache configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # ...
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/'">
        Header Set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header Set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
        Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
        Header Unset ETag
        FileETag None
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

For IIS server, see [How to disable caching of single page application HTML file served through IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600845/how-to-disable-caching-of-single-page-application-html-file-served-through-iis)

Answer (score 0):

For that u can set IIS not to cache index.html file.  for that you have to simply include web.config file in to your www folder and add this settings in to it.

```
  <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```