# Why is server ignoring changes in the code files even though cache is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, server, iis-7, browser-cache

I test an html/js code on my localhost (Windows 7, Chrome v79.0.3945.130 (64-bit)) and about 50% of the time code changes are not reflected in the browser (I see it with Dev Tools/Sources).
There are a ton of advice on the internet, but neither seems to work:

- Rightclick on the reload and chose "Empty cache and Hard reload" -
  doesn't help in 30% of the cases.
- Disable cache in the Network tab of the Chrome Dev Tools - doesn't help.
- Add `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">` in the header - doesn't help.
- Replace `<script src="common.js"></script>` by `<script src="common.js?blabla"></script>` - helps in 60% of the cases, but you need to do it after every change is a huge chore. Also, it doesn't work with html changes.
- Copy a file to a new file (like index.html to index2.html) and replace the file name in the code - always works, but it is an even bigger chore.

The exact same problem present when I commit the code to github.io

Please help me to make it so the site reflects the code changes immediately.

---

Edit: I've created a file index3.html and put only "hello world" there. Opened the file in the browser. Changed to "hello world2" - the browser updated the content. Changed to  "hello world3" - the browser still was showing  "hello world2" even after multiple reloads and "Empty cache and hard reload". I changed to "hello world4" - the browser still showed "hello world2". In for 4 hours I changed to "hello world5" - the browser still shows "hello world2". This file I edited with basic notepad.

---

Edit2: People keep asking what server I'm using. This looks like a part of the problem. Unfortunately, I don't know and neither do i know what exactly I need to do to check it. Here is all I've found out so far:

- I have `inetpub/wwwroot` directory where I put html & js files and
  then open index.html in a browser at `http://localhost/`.
- My Network panel in Devs Tools looks like this: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBOvy.jpg).
- The server setup was very fast and didn't require any additional software to install. I.e. I'm not using node.js.
- There is iisstart.htm at `inetpub/wwwroot` and when I open `http://localhost/iisstart.htm` it says IIS7.

Comment: I sometimes find the disabling the cache in chrome dev tools + refreshing + enabling the cache again + refreshing sometimes fixes the issue? Might be worth a shot...

Comment: what type of server are you using?

Comment: @Jhecht how do I check it?

Comment: are you using node.js web server or is it python web server? providing this information would help.

Comment: @mamounothman how do I check it?

Comment: are you using a programming language for serve the HTML, or maybe you are using apache, nginx ..etc? or are you opening the HTML file directly in the browser?

Comment: If you are debugging from visual studio, it'd most probably be an iisexpress

Comment: @mamounothman I just open html in the browser. I did a very simple setup few months ago, it was so quick that I"m failing completely to recall what exactly I did. Now I just have inetpub/wwwroot directory where I put html & js files and then open index.html in a browser.

Comment: @klm123 can you make a simple .html file write "hello world" in it open it in browser and then again change the content "hello new world" then again open the file in browser and let us know if your .html changes not reflecting in browser ? and also show us the URL of your local file ?

Comment: @klm123 for your local changes or development, you can use (CTRL+F5 to reload ) in chrome and better if you use Firefox ( use CTRL+R to reload )

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">` is the right way to do it. Unfortunately, this is for each document and you are writing it in your HTML-page. You have to write it in your javascript file. But you can't write it inside the script itself... So you have to set it in the request-header. One way would be to write a php script and add the headers. Another one is setting your (Apache) server to add the headers for this script.

Comment: @AabirHussain see the edit at the bottom of the post. I do use CTRL+R and right click on the reload symbol to reload.

Comment: After you change the index file. Have you checked for updates in other browsers? Are you using APS.NET MVC? Are you using an IIS system server or local IIS from VS?

Comment: If you use IIS. Have you checked server caching settings? There is a separate item in the settings "Caching output data".

Comment: From what I see in answers you probably will work around it with a parameter. And that probably will work. However, normally this shouldn't be necessary when you disable the cache in chrome dev tools. So my hunch would be there is another cache involved. Between you and the server could be any number of additional caching technology. A few examples: Server side caching (eg Varnish), CDN caching (eg Cloudflare), local proxies from router/firewalls (eg squid-cache) and similar things. I'd check for those as well.

Comment: @AleksandrSmityukh, no, i use only Chrome. And I have no idea what are all these names are.

Comment: @klm123 to get some useful help here you should _really_ specify what kind of web server you are using to serve the files to chrome! Since opening devTools should disable client-side caching it is probably an issue with **server-side** caching.

What do you mean by _Now I just [...] open index.html in a browser_? Do you open it from the file explorer and the URL in the address bar begins with `file:/// ...`? Then you're opening it as local file and there is no web server involved.

Otherwise opening it via `http://localhost`  you need to check the caching config of your local web server.

Comment: @acran I check it on http://localhost by using dev tools/Sources. Many people ask for what server I'm using, but, unfortunately, no one specifies exactly what should I do to provide you that information. Neither anyone says how to disable cache in the cache config of the server.

Comment: @klm123 without knowing which web server this is about it is impossible to tell you, how to change or check the cache config for it.

If you have no idea about your web server one possible way to check for it is in the network tab of the devTools: check the response headers of the loaded `index.html` for something like a `X-Powered-By` or `Server` header which might give a hint on the web server.
Googling for your file path `inetpub/wwwroot` strongly points to a IIS server.

Comment: @acran I don't see anything like that https://imgur.com/b1AFupn  But I looked for ISS in the windows - and I remember that application window - I tried to change something there soon after server setup, but haven't found any kind of helpful option.

Comment: @klm123 I am unable to generate your case in my system, I have trying MAC, Ubuntu but still unable to generate your case. Can you provide some more information of your system configurations ? and are you using any web server on local machine ? issue is occur on local machine right ? browser version etc

Comment: Did you just double-click the html file(s) and it opened on your browser or did you do anything first in your terminal maybe (to start a server that loads your html)? Because if it was the former, you wouldn't have `http://localhost/name-of-file` as the url of your local file but instead have `file://pathtofile/name-of-file` as the url.

Comment: @AabirHussain Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit). And you need to specify your question about local machine. As I told, I open http://localhost, can it still be a remote machine somehow?

Comment: @acran There is iisstart.htm at `inetpub/wwwroot` when I open localhost/iisstart.htm it says IIS7. Is this the server?

Comment: @klm123 I did'nt see your last edit thats why I have asked you about local machine and web server. Its clear that you are using windows with IIS web server on your local machine.  Please have a look on this => https://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/caching-in-iis7.

Answer (score 5):

Using a parameter is the right way! Here you can add a version number you only change on big changes manually and for debugging you can set it to Date.time() so in your < head> tag, this forces all cached versions to be overwritten as the parameter is always a new one:

```
< script type="text/javascript"> 
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    var version = Date.time();
    script.src = "common.js?v="+version; 
    document.head.appendChild(script) 
< /script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess I can do it. But isn't it effectively the same as my fourth option? to add "?blabla" after the file name. It doesn't work quite often - it's either the same file name in the Sources tab, or blabla is added, but the content of the file is still the same.

Comment: It's not the same. Once a parameter is used twice (which will never happen with Date.time() it may render a cached version. ?blabla is the same after using it twice as not using it at all.

Comment: parameter is not used twice. I edit code, then change the parameter, then check source code in the browser and it is the old one.

Comment: Your approach helps, thank you. But it doesn't solve my problem. What you wrote is not true in my situation. "forces all cached versions to be overwritten as the parameter is always a new one", changing the parameter to a new one doesn't force my cache to reload reliably. Also it can't help with changes in index.html.

Answer (score 4):

In IIS7 Windows server running on Windows 7, to prevent caching of your content, you need to make some changes to your one of your configuration files called `web.config`. The configuration files for IIS 7 and later are located in `%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config folder` where `%WinDir%` is the folder where you installed Windows (usually `C:/Windows`).

Create a backup copy of your `web.config` file before editing it so you can rollback to it if the changes you'll make to the file breaks it.

In your `web.config` file, just add the following to prevent caching of your `index.html`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

---

Got the file path for the `web.config` file from here: [Windows Doc: Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/)

Got the configuration for the cache above from here: [How to disable caching of single page application HTML file served through IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26666450/4114907)

Comment: There is no web.config at the mentioned path. I've created it and put your code there. But I had to replace index.html by full path like `projectName/index.html`, which I copy from url in my browser `http:/localhost/projectName/index.html`. Result - no effect on the caching problem.

Comment: @kim123 Can you try adding the `web.config` file in the root folder of your site (folder where your site is in) instead and changing the path back to just `index.html` and see if that works.

Comment: i did. it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and this is my checklist:

1. Check **web.config** (caching and clientcache, kernel cache policy etc.) or **.htaccess** (Header set Cache-Control).
2. If you used dynamic languages like ASP, PHP there might be internal cache setting. In one case I found `<%Response.Expires=1440%>` within many lines of ASP code and it was overcoming all other settings! In php `session_cache_expire` may does the same.
3. If you are using IIS then check the **server** > **HTTP Response headers** to make sure there is nothing about caching also the same for individual websites listed under the server name.
4. check `http-equiv="Cache-control"` in html headers ( you passed this test! ).

Finally I have to say that in all situations above, Checking **Disable cache** in **newtwork** tab in Chrome console always worked for me to view a fresh version of pages however this is good only for debugging purposes and visitors wont do that!

Comment: 1. Where do I find web.config and .htaccess? 2. I use html and js only. 3. HTTP Response headers looks like this: https://imgur.com/leYpdej

Comment: If you are using IIS the web.congfig is in the root ot wwwroot. Aslo there is Machine.config file in server level which you can modify it from IIS console of directly from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config. If you are using apache server on windows please serach windows to  find .htaccess @klm123

Answer (score 0):

What you write in HTML meta is a recommendation to browsers, not a strict instruction. If strict caching is enabled in the browser, this will not help.

The solutions are described well: https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting/

I prefer on the server side to add to the scripts the version with the date of the last update of the file itself.

```
<script src="/myScript.js?v=1579780745150"></script>
```

Where **1579780745150** is Unix Timestamp updates the **myScript.js** file itself. It works only with its own files, but external ones are not needed. Most often in the file name is the version.

Comment: If you need the code of backend. Tell me which platform you used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer's updates, I would say that your issue is caused by [IIS](https://www.iis.net/) v7 that it uses your PC **Memory** for caching not you local Hard drive that's why `Hard reload` and all other method seems to not work properly.

I could think of 3 solution:

**1. Fixing your IIS cache issue:** (Not tested due the fact that i don't have a PC with IIS)

1. From **Start** menu, click **Administrative Tools**, and then click **Internet Information Services** (IIS) Manager. (see [Images](http://duhjones.com/steps-to-open-the-iis-manager-in-windows-7/))
2. In the **tree** view on the **left side**, find your application.
3. Select the **Output Caching** menu item.
4. Click on **Add Cache Rule** then type the file `extension`s that you want to disable cache on them i.e. `.aspx`, .css, .js etc... (one at the time I guess?)
5. Now, you can either you Untick **user-mode caching** or Check **prevent all caching.** It should look similar to this:

[image]

[Solution Source](https://superuser.com/questions/63014/how-do-i-turn-off-caching-in-iis7) - Read more about [IIS 7 Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching)

---

**2. Using some alternatives to IIS** There are quite a few but i'd recommend (based on my experiences) [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) Both will give you a better development "environment"  and both support Windows 7. Also, if you're familiar with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you can just use [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension.

---

**3. Use Chrome** [Incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) mode while developing. (Not sure if it works for IIS7)

Comment: Add Cache Rule/Prevent all caching - doesn't help [tried with html]. Incognito mode - doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried with `.js` files? it depends on what changes are you make.

Answer (score -1):

This is a long shot - but what sort of editor/IDE are you using?
Also, what sort of edits are you making to your index.html?

Could you provide some examples of such edits that aren't being reflected when you save and try to load the file?

I'd like to try to reproduce your issue. From what people are suggesting, it doesn't appear that the problem is within the code itself. I suspect it is an environmental issue but I'd need more info from you to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: I use microsoft visual studio code. Example: replace <script src="common.js"></script> by <script src="common.js?blabla">. Example2: add a new button, add a new div, add onload function call. Tbh it looks like any kind of edits.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably really frustrating, and it doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong.

The problem is likely that something between your browser and the script file you are calling doing some caching.

To determine what it is, let me ask how are you browsing to the localhost url?

Examples:

```
file://path/to/file.html
http://localhost/file.html
http://127.0.0.1/file.html
http://[machine's-hostname]/file.html
http://[custom-domain-defined-in-hosts-file]/file.html
```

If you are running `file://path/to/file.html` this means you are not browsing through a web server/proxy. If it is `http://[something]/file.html` then you are running some kind of web server and that is likely the culprit. Look for some kind of setting where you can turn off caching.

If you are not using a web server and are literally browsing directly to a local html file without a web server, then I would suggest the browser is the culprit. If this is the case, I'd suggest turning off browser caching like [Martin Shishkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59809164/2285092) suggested.

Comment: it's ```http://localhost/ProjectName/index.html``` Where this setting where you can turn off caching can be?

Comment: It looks like from the screen shot you posted elsewhere, you are using IIS, (also called Microsoft's Internet Information Services).


A quick solution is to just double-click on your .html file to load it in the browser, which will use a `file://path/to/projectName/index.html`. That will remove the web server from the equation.

To continue using IIS and just fix the cache, refer to this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/247404/how-to-modify-the-cache-control-http-header-when-you-use-iis

Answer (score -1):

Chrome does this thing where, if file hasn’t changed too much, not sure what it means, it will use the “compiled” cache version. For html it means parsed don tree. For JS precompiled code etc.

There is usually ways to address this, many frameworks use hash inside filenames, like: `main.md5hash.js`, because changing file name invalidates any cache.

Then you will be left with possibly html not updating. And to be clear, I am not sure, you can always add comment with random blob... like a date.

Answer (score -2):

In the specific case with using Google Chrome, try this:
Open Dev Tools -> Go to 'Network' tab. Check 'Disable cache' checkbox, after that refresh the page.

> NOTE: In order for this to work every time the Dev Tools window MUST
>   stay open at all times.

[image]

However, in order to propagate changes to your users, without having them to hard refresh the page, etc, you have to append file versions at the end of each referenced file for files that change frequently (just as you pointed out).
For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=20b379f72a37" >
```

The `v=20b379f72a37` appended to the end is an auto-generated file hash of the file contents.

Comment: Thats the item 2 in my list.

Comment: Are you making sure Dev Tools window stays open?

Comment: the dev tools window is open, the check box is checked [but I look at the sources tab usually], and I even do hard refresh.